# ADF af:showPrintablePageBehavior sends all subsequent navigation commands to a new window

Tags: java, oracle-adf

I have a print icon that renders the printable version of the form.

```
<af:link id="printButton" icon="/images/printer.png">
   <af:showPrintablePageBehavior/>
</af:link>
```

This part works properly, but after you close the tab created by the `<af:showPrintablePageBehavior/>` any attempts to redirect to a new page creates a new browser tab.

The button doing the redirect is defined thusly,

```
<af:button text="Search" action="#{backing.searchAction}" 
           partialSubmit="false" immediate="true" id="ab1" />

public String searchAction() {
    return "search" 
}
```

`"search"` is a navigation-rule, which is defined in the `faces-config.xml` and works properly if you do not invoke `<af:showPrintablePageBehavior/>` before clicking the button.

I have tried using `ExternalContext.redirect(page)`. I have also tried defining the `targetFrame` attribute to `_self` and `_parent` for the `<af:button>`. The miss-behavior is consistent with each of these approaches.

Comment: Another note on this, I caught the `UIComponent` in the back end and printed out the attributes, the `targetFrame=_self` as expected.

Comment: Using JDeveloper 12c

Comment: A question - are you working within a bounded taskflow?

Comment: No, unbounded task flow. Thanks for looking into it.

Comment: The work around accepted worked as a temporary solution. Oracle issued a patch in June-July 2015 timeframe to address and fix this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The root of all evil in your example is the `immediate="true"` attribute. If you just remove it, you'll get your problem solved.

However, in order to explain why, let's first start with the `<af:showPrintablePageBehaviour>` component and the `trinidad-config.xml` file (which is nested within the `WEB-INF` folder).

The `trinidad-config.xml` file lists an element, called `<output-mode>`. By default, it's not there, but you can add it manually. The element supports three values:

- `"default"` (or `null`): the default output mode
- `"printable"`: an output mode suitable for printable pages
- `"email"`: an output mode suitable for e-mailing a page's content

In order to have a page content displayed as a printable, the `output-mode` is changed (usually by the underlying framework) to `"printable"`. So, every time you click on your `<af:link>` component, the `<output-mode>` value is set to `"printable"`.

The good thing about `trinidad-config.xml` is that we are allowed to use EL expressions within, which means that we can dynamically change the value of the `<output-mode>` element. For example, the value can be read from a `@ManagedBean`:

```
 <output-mode>#{printableBehaviorBean.outputMode}</output-mode>
```

The been itself can be a completely simple (`@RequestScoped`) bean. Note that I'm using annotations instead of XML-based configuration, because you mentioned you're using ADF 12c, which is built on the top of JSF-2.

```
@RequestScoped
@ManagedBean(name = "printableBehaviorBean")
public class PrintableBehaviorBean {
    private String outputMode;

    public void setOutputMode(String outputMode) {
        this.outputMode = outputMode;
    }

    public String getOutputMode() {
        return outputMode;
    }
}
```

Then, we can *inject* this bean within another bean, which will help us navigate to the `"search"` activity when the `Search` button is pressed. The bean will have a nested `@ManagedProperty` member, which will hold an instance of the preceding `printableBehaviorBean` bean. Also, the `navigationBean` will introduce a `search()` method, which we'll be referred from the `Search` button's `action` attribute.

The trick here's that before actually returning the navigation outcome, we'll change the value of the `outputMode` property in the `printableBehaviorBean`. Remember that this new value will overwrite the existing `<output-mode>` value and if the `<output-mode>` value was previously set to `"printable"`, it will be reverted back to `"default"` (and this will happen every time we click the on `Search` button).

```
@RequestScoped
@ManagedBean(name = "navigationBean")
public class NavigationBean {

    @ManagedProperty(name = "printableBehaviorBean", value="#{printableBehaviorBean}")
    private PrintableBehaviorBean printableBehaviorBean;

    public void setPrintableBehaviorBean(PrintableBehaviorBean printableBehaviorBean) {
        this.printableBehaviorBean = printableBehaviorBean;
    }

    public PrintableBehaviorBean getPrintableBehaviorBean() {
        return printableBehaviorBean;
    }

    public String search() {
        printableBehaviorBean.setOutputMode("default");
        return "search";
    }

}
```

And finally, the `Search` button definition would be changed slightly to:

```
<af:button text="Search" action="#{navigationBean.search}" immediate="true" id="ab1" />
```

---

Now, another question of interest would be *"Why removing `immediate="true"` solves the problem?*.

A `UICommand` component decorated with `immediate="true"` will make the framework skip the "Process validations", "Update model values" and "Invoke application" JSF life-cycle phases (i.e. the 3rd, 4th and the 5th phase). My assumption on your problem would be that before the "Invoke application" phase, the ADF implementation **checks** if the command components is decorated with a `<af:showPrintablePageBehaviour>` component and if it is, then it programmatically changes the value of the `<output-mode>` element. And since you have `immediate="true"` on the `"Search"` button, this value would be left as `"printable"`. That's why when you go back to the form, it triggers a new tab.

So, in conclusion, *either* remove the `immediate="true"` attribute, *or* follow the workaround with the beans I suggested.

Comment: Removing `immediate="true"` did not work, will attempt the work around. Thanks for the research!

Comment: `partialSubmit` is `false` by default. I guess you just had to redeploy the application :)

Comment: That's what I thought as well, you're probably right, did a clean build after the `partialSubmit` change.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using ADF 12c and Konstantin Yovkov described the problem, maybe you can remove the inmediate attribute and put inside af:button

```
<af:target events="@all" execute="@this" render="@all"/>
```